# django PasswordInput()

Tags: python, django

в форму передается

```
password = forms.CharField(max_length=10, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
```

в поле формы отображается

```
<django.forms.widgets.PasswordInput object at 0x0359CC50>
```

Почему так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код абсолютно рабочий и нет разницы передавать туда класс или экземпляр класса - django сама разбирается что вы ей передали. В качестве подтверждения аналогичности код:

```
class foo(forms.Form):
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=10, widget=forms.PasswordInput())

class bar(forms.Form):
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=10, widget=forms.PasswordInput)

print(foo())
print(bar())
```

выведет

```
<tr><th><label for="id_password">Password:</label></th><td><input id="id_password" maxlength="10" name="password" type="password" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_password">Password:</label></th><td><input id="id_password" maxlength="10" name="password" type="password" /></td></tr>
```

Как видите результат абсолютно идентичный. Покажите как вы выводите форму в шаблоне - скорее всего проблема именно в этом.

Comment: Проблема уже решена и была именно в этом,спасибо за оказанное внимание